# Scrolling a wide image using imageview (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, scrollview

I've been trying to get a big image (10345x1280 px) to fit on my android screen (in landscape mode) basically I want the 1280px dimension to fit to the height of the screen and I want the longer dimension to be scrollable from left to right.

I've been using various methods but really not having much luck either due to the scrolling not working or the image not being scaled correctly. Right now I'm trying to use an imageview within a scrollview and the main issue is that embedding the imageview in the scrollview messes up the scaling of the image. The attached photos show the comparison before and after the imageview is embededded in the scroll view.

The first image is the ideal im trying to achieve with scrolling so if anyone has an idea on what the best way to go about this, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNF35.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Q85.png

EDIT: I made some adjustments to the xml code, I also resized my image to have a height of 400 (so its now 3233x400). The picture fits better on the screen now, but still not perfect, and it scrolls up/down but not left right as I need it to.... There must be a way to properly fit an image so that the height fills the screen on all device types?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            tools:context=".HelpActivity"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageHelp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fretz" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the xml code in here so we can debug it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of problems in your layout first of all the nested layout within the ScrollView a `LinearLayout` that only holds ImageView which is unnecessary, Also `ScrollView` will automatically scroll the vertical axis of the Image not its Horizontal axis consider using `HorizontalScrollView` that fit in your needs.

I remake your layout with the use of `HorizontalScrollView` to scroll on it **horizontally** which work perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="SAMPLE"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageHelp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/lal" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks much for the answer, I also figured out on my own that I was supposed to use HorizontalScrollview, doh. Anyway, I still have a couple problems, not sure if you can help. As expected, the scroll starts at the far left of the image, however the image is not displayed from its far left end, i'd say there is probably a 1/4 of the image missing on the left side that is unreachable. Additionally, i can keep scrolling right far past the edge of the image.

Comment: @user67081 use the above xml and see the result.

Comment: Ahh thanks, should've read your post more carefully. It was indeed the linearlayout causing problems (among other things). It works as intended, thanks very again!